# git-flow vs. normal git commands

Tags: git, git-flow

I've read a couple of information about git-flow, but still don't understand why it should be used instead of plain git commands. To me it looks like it propagates a (fairly complicated) branch-setup. OK, this should be easily adoptable. Git-flow also adds some higher-level commands around the lower-level, normal git commands.

Could someone please explain in only a few words the benefits of using git-flow over using plain git commands?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe git-flow allows you to implement a certain process within the dev team. It enforces certain practices such as naming conventions for your branches and assists with the `flow` from development, to release, to master.

git-flow doesn't offer anything that basic git commands can't do. With the `start` and `finish` commands it abstracts away the merging and deleting.

Benefits are:

- enforces a process (flow) by having known branch types: `master`, `develop`, `release`, `hotfix`
- standardizes branch naming conventions
- abstracts certain git commands for merging and deleting

Comment: So git-flow only adds value by creating branches ("add a feature"), merging them and deleting them after-wards ("finish a feature")?

Comment: @MikeL. More or less, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Git Flow follows the branching model described in [A successful branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/). Of course you can do all that with standard Git commands but Git Flow just encapsulates some of the conventions, especially naming related ones, into additional commands that just help to follow the branching model.

Answer (score 3):

It just encourages a consistent branch naming and integration style in your repo, which can be helpful when working among several people. Consistently named branches make it immediately obvious what "style" a branch is: a new feature, a small bug fix, or a release.

You don't necessarily need to use the git-flow tools themselves to accomplish it, and the author originally just described the process itself in a [blog post](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) without having the git-flow tools at all.